# collective.plonetruegallery won't work in Plone 4.0

Tags: image, plone, buildout

I can't get `collective.plonetruegallery` properly working in my Plone 4.0 server. 
I have changed the buildout.cfg file in the `[versions]` part and added the following lines:

```
z3c.form = 2.3.2
plone.app.z3cform = 0.5.0
plone.z3cform = 0.6.0
zope.schema = 3.6.0k
```

After this modification I run the buildout again with sudo ./bin/buildout
When I want to add the product there is no available product `collective.plonetruegallery`.

In the webpage is mentioned to reinstall Plone z3cform support. Could this be a solution ?

Thanks in advance,

Bas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation instructions on http://plone.org/products/plone-true-gallery assume that you know how to add an egg to a Plone buildout; the instructions there are in *addition* to the normal egg installation procedures.

Add the egg to the `[instance]` part:

```
[instance]
... other options ...
eggs +=
    collective.plonetruegalery
```

Comment: Here with our buildout.cfg file. Works nice with Plone 4.1  !